# Does CSS have anything like jQuery's :has()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css, css-selectors

In CSS (any version), is there something like, or any other way of doing anything like the `:has()` selector in jQuery?

> `jQuery(':has(selector)')`
>
> **Description:** Selects elements which
>   contain at least one element that
>   matches the specified selector.

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: what do you want to ask for in the has()-selector?

Comment: Isn't that just a normal child selector? The rules in a selector will be applied to all elements that match.

Comment: @andyb: `:has()` is a conditional pseudo-class, similar to `:not()`. The elements matched are the selectors around the pseudo-class, not in the brackets.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah I got it, my mistake :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. The way CSS is designed, does not permit selectors that match ancestors or preceding siblings; only descendants ( and `>`), succeeding siblings (`~` and `+`) or specific children (`:*-child`). The only ancestor selector is the `:root` pseudo-class which selects the root element of a document (in HTML pages, naturally it would be `html`).

If you need to apply styles to the element you're querying with `:has()`, you need to add a CSS class to it then style by that class, [as suggested by Stargazer712](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6279001/106224).

Comment: The Selectors 4 drafts mention a subject selector that, although it has a different semantic to jQuery's `:has()` selector, would work just as well in this case if it gets standardized and implemented.

Answer (score 5):

No. The best way to accomplish this is by using jQuery:

Css File:

```
.myAwesomeClass {
    ...
}
```

Js File:

```
jQuery(':has(selector)').addClass("myAwesomeClass")
```

where `selector` is whatever it is you were originally trying to match.

Comment: The *best* way would be to organise your CSS and markup to make it unnecessary to rely on JavaScript, even if CSS is a bit of a pain sometimes.