# Selecting different parts of css selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible in a selector like this:

```
div table
```

Select the divs that have been filtered? As in divs that contain a table instead of all tables that are in divs.

Comment: The CSS WG is tossing up an idea of a [subject selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) in CSS4. We shall see how this goes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS selectors can not ascend. It is one of their [limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations).

Also see [Does CSS have anything like jQuery's :has()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278919/does-css-have-anything-like-jquerys-has)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can normally solve this problem with adding classes to your div elements, to help differentiate them from other divs.

Answer (score 0):

This can however be done with Jquery with `.parent()` `.parents()` or `:parent`Might be something work checking out.